# jQuery zClip - how do I change the height of the div?

Tags: jquery, css, styles, zclip

I'm trying to modify this output;

```
<div class="snippet-clipboard" style="position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 20px; z-index: 99; left: 771px; top: 362px; "><embed id="ZeroClipboardMovie_1" src="zclip/ZeroClipboard.swf" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="30" height="20" name="ZeroClipboardMovie_1" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="id=1&amp;width=30&amp;height=20" wmode="transparent"></div>
```

I want to change the height of the snippet-clipboard class from 20px to 30px but I can't seem to do it, I assume it's in jquery.zclip.js ([link](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.zclip.js)).

If anyone could help me, that'd be great!

Edit;
This is an extract from jquery.zclip.js:

```
// create floating DIV above element
        this.div = document.createElement('div');
        this.div.className = "zclip";
        this.div.id = "zclip-" + this.movieId;
        $(this.domElement).data('zclipId', 'zclip-' + this.movieId);
        var style = this.div.style;
        style.position = 'absolute';
        style.left = '' + box.left + 'px';
        style.top = '' + box.top + 'px';
        style.width = '' + box.width + 'px';
        style.height = '' + box.height + 'px';
        style.zIndex = zIndex;
```

Comment: you should probably put your code together and make a sample on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Well, it should be pretty simple. I just want to change the CSS to change the height, that's all..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
width="30" height="30" 
flashvars="id=1&amp;width=30&amp;height=30"
```